# Android canvas clicks not available

Tags: android, kotlin

I am exploring android canvas (in Kotlin) and it looks very cool. But I found one limitation to the things I could do with canvas. I  want someone experienced to confirm my thinking or give me some hack which is used to resolve this issue. Here it goes:

By my understanding canvas is used for drawing. It is creating ONE view and I am able ONLY to put clickListener to the whole view I created in my CustomView class (class in which I used canvas and did drawing).

Is this true? If that is true I am unable to do complex views with Textviews, EditTexts and Buttons combined with drawing part all together in one CustomView. That would be pity if that's so.

Please tell me is this true and if not what is the hack/catch I am missing here.

Answer (score -1):

Canvas is just an object that supports "*drawing pixels over a 2D Bitmap/Surface*" in the View area. Nothing more.

Words similar to "*I would lime to draw a TextView in a Canvas*" means nothing because you cannot draw an Object (in this example the TextView) on a Canvas.

Drawing procedure is very complex and suppose all "things to be drawn" are PIXELS or primitive shapes (lines, squares, rectangles, ovals, etc...).

A **TextView** is an active object made by few rectangles (mainly as background) and it manages its own drawing procedure. It has its own Canvas in which it draws all "graphics" (mainly then background and text) and each generated Event (click, move, ecc..) (could)change how/what its Canvas draws.

If you want to "*draw EditText on a Canvas*" you have to create ALL EDITEXT PIXELS by your own and then draw them on the Canvas, but in this way you have to manage clicks and key stroke events by your own based on WHERE (x,y coordinate) the event was generated.